# I am working on blobstore in GAE . My upload URL is visible in the console and not in the localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

How do you retrieve a blobkey from the datastore in google appengine using java.?

Comment: when you say "visible in the console", you mean in the developer's console? then when you say localhost... do you mean the devserver? make this question clearer please, include something you've tried, or what error you're getting from your code or... well pretty much anything at this point

Answer (score 1):

```
 Query= new Query("__BlobInfo__"); // this doesnt work

 BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey();
// Is there a Query like feature as in the datastore to access entities for        blobstore... i need the key of the blob here to view the image on a seperate jsp page//
  blobstoreService .serve(blobKey ,res);
```